# getting calling module name when using import method - python

Tags: python, logging, import

I implemented my own logger inside my automation framework *(based on pytest)* which inherits from `logging.Logger` class.

Now I want it on each time it is imported by some module using the following command:
`from framework import Logger as logger` to create child with the calling module name.

I know some code inside the class can be run when importing it to another module, so I want this code to create the logger child.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the calling module name, I tried to use `inspect.stack()`  but  I get a huge list that I don't know how to handle with.

Is there any other way I can implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible, You have to pass logger as an argument for your particular use case.

```
   from utils import do_something
   logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

   do_something()  # logger global is not visible in do_something()
   do_something(logger=logger)  # the only way
```

other option is to have trace as [logging doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)

```
logger.warning("something raised an exception:", exc_info=True)
```